# How to query all the versions from delta lake table at once to track changes made to a specific ID

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, delta-lake

I have an employee table with `salary` of all the `employee`s managed using delta lake.

I can query the table based on the *version* or the *timestamp* using the time travel feature delta lake supports like this.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM DELTA.`EMPLOYEE`
VERSION AS OF 3
```

But I want to know the history of all the changes done to an employee across all the versions of the delta table. Something like this

```sql
SELECT *
, timestamp -- From delta table
, version -- From delta table
FROM DELTA.`EMPLOYEE`
WHERE EMPLOYEE = 'George'
WITHIN ALL VERSIONS --Never exists but just for understanding
```

Comment: afaik delta-lake does not provide record level history of changes...

Answer (score 4):

On Databricks, starting with the Databricks Runtime 8.2 there is a functionality called [Change Data Feed](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-change-data-feed.html) that tracks what changes were made to the table, and you can pull that feed of changes either as batch or as stream for analysis or implementing change data capture-style processing.

After change data feed is enabled on the table, you can read data using batch or stream APIs, something like this:

```py
spark.read.format("delta") \
  .option("readChangeFeed", "true") \
  .option("startingVersion", 0) \
  .table("myDeltaTable")
```

and you'll get all changed records with [additional columns](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-change-data-feed.html#change-data-event-schema) that describe what kind of changes was done (insert/update/delete), when this happened (timestamp) and in which version.

Update, September 2022: Change Data Feed is now available in the open source version as well - starting with version 2.0.0.

Comment: you can enable the feed in python by running `spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.properties.defaults.enableChangeDataFeed", True)`

Comment: I’m not sure if it’s supported in open source version

Comment: Could be, ran this in databricks community

Comment: Community edition != open source

Comment: Happy to support paid version. Do you know if there is a native query for  `spark.read.format("delta").option("readChangeFeed", "true").option("startingVersion", 0).load(tblpath).sort(['name','date','_commit_version']).dropDuplicates(subset=['name','date'])` ? Ie for all the data in the table, get the earliest value for each record.

Answer (score 2):

It is an old question but today I stumbled on it, since I had some problem to solve. I don't think Delta (delta.io) provides a method for this because Delta revolves around Time Travel to a specific point in time rather over a period.

But if I have to get this, I guess one way will be to directly read the parquet files (ignore delta logs), which will result in all the past versions/states of the record (leave Vacuum etc. aside).

Now if the requirement is to get the exact version of each record creation (which is my requirement), use something like

`dataframe.withColumn("input_file", input_file_name())`
which will show the exact file name the record is coming from.

Now query the .json _delta_log transaction files which will tell us which version has added which file, something like this

```
>>> details = spark.read.json('/data/gcs/delta/ingest/bigtable/_delta_log/*.json')
>>> details = details.select(col('add')['path'].alias("file_path")).withColumn("version",substring(input_file_name(),-6,1)).filter("file_path is not NULL")
>>> details.show(5,100)
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|                                                          file_path|version|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|part-00000-148c98cc-0db1-495e-bb67-0ba1cc4fd45e-c000.snappy.parquet|      4|
|part-00001-2caa89b7-c990-47e0-b7b0-92430b15b141-c000.snappy.parquet|      4|
|part-00002-1f900af7-d819-48e9-a048-ad22e5c7ce65-c000.snappy.parquet|      4|
|part-00003-e043f466-861b-47f0-a1cf-4b67e75a5ed2-c000.snappy.parquet|      4|
|part-00000-93cc0747-ca0b-46ef-ada4-b3fb18e48925-c000.snappy.parquet|      0|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

join both of these dataframes on file_path and you will see each state/version of the record along with the delta version it was created in. My example -

```
parquet_table = spark.read.parquet('/data/gcs/delta/ingest/bigtable/*.parquet')

>>> parquet_table.printSchema()
root
 |-- Region: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Country: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Item_Type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Sales_Channel: string (nullable = true)


parquet_table = parquet_table.where(col("Order_ID")==913712584).\
            withColumn("input_file",substring(input_file_name(),38,1000)).\
           select(["Order_ID","Region","Country","Sales_Channel","input_file"]).\
            orderBy("Country")
            
>>> parquet_table.join(details,parquet_table.input_file == details.file_path).select("Order_ID","Region","Country","Sales_Channel","version").orderBy("version").show(100)
+---------+------------------+-------+-------------+-------+                    
| Order_ID|            Region|Country|Sales_Channel|version|
+---------+------------------+-------+-------------+-------+
|913712584|Sub-Saharan Africa|Lesotho|       Online|      0|
|913712584|Sub-Saharan Africa|Lesotho|       Online|      0|
|913712584|Sub-Saharan Africa|Lesotho|       Online|      0|
```

Comment: Files could be compacted creating a new version. Also, it won’t track the updates/deletes